# Reference a custom form field's attribute from controller on CakePHP

Tags: forms, cakephp, attributes, custom-attributes

My question is the next:

I am developing a CakePHP 2 application.

I want to access to a field's attribute of a view from the controller. Is there any option to do it?

For example, I have an input field like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Permission.permissions',array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => __('Añade permisos',true),
        'after' => __('Separa cada permiso con una coma.  Ej: view, edit, remove',true),
        'category' => $cat
                ));
```

Then I want to refrence the (custom) category attribute from the Controller.

I hope you can solve it. Thanks

Comment: use hidden fields to solve this problem

Comment: `__('Añade permisos',true)` This is not Cake2 but Cake1 syntax!

Comment: @Anilkumar the solution was simple... I can't believe it! Thanks

Comment: @mark You have reason, I pasted a piece of code from Internet. At least I have learned one thing more (I ignored its meaning). Thanks

Comment: Why not just reading the official documentation instead of trusting some old outdated stuff on the internet? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html